# bash : parse output of command and store into variable

Tags: bash, variables, command

I have made a command witch return 'version:X' .

ie:

```
$>./mybox -v
$>version:2
```

I don't understand why this isn't working :

```
 $>VERSION=$( /home/mybox -v | sed 's/.*version:\([0-9]*\).*/\1/')
 $>echo $VERSION
 $>
```

if I write this, it is ok :

```
 $>VERSION=$( echo "version:2" | sed 's/.*version:\([0-9]*\).*/\1/')
 $>echo $VERSION
 $>2
```

Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's pretty common for version/error/debugging information to be sent to `stderr`, not `stdout`. When running the command from a terminal, both will be printed, but only `stdout` will make it through the pipe to `sed`.

`echo` output always goes to `stdout` by default, which is why you're not having trouble there.

If the above is correct, you'll just need to redirect `stderr` (file descriptor 2) to `stdout` (file descriptor 1) before passing it along:

```
VERSION=$( /home/mybox -v 2>&1 | sed 's/.*version:\([0-9]*\).*/\1/')
#                         ^^^^
```

Comment: Wouldn't "version:2" appear at the console in this case? It doesn't in the example in the question.

Comment: @Sleafar Typically yes, unless it was ignored in copy-paste or an artifact of console line-overwriting. This could have been a comment, but it was getting long and I decided to go with the hunch instead.